# expanding listview custom component with button click

Tags: android, listview, custom-component

i'm developing a small application in with a list view filled with a compound component. This component has two text view and one button inside. One of the text view is invisible and when the button is clicked it should appear. I can show the list but i can't make the textview visible when the button is clicked.
Here is the xml of the component:

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView 
  android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
  android:id="@+id/placeNamwView" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:textSize="30dp" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:maxWidth="250dp">
  </TextView>
 <Button 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/placeNamwView" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/Button01" 
  android:text="More">
  </Button>
 <EditText 
  android:layout_below="@+id/placeNamwView" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
  android:id="@+id/placeAddressView" 
  android:textSize="20dp" 
  android:textColor="#FFFF0000" 
  android:maxWidth="250dp">
  </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the ArrayAdapter that fills the list:

```
   public class AddressAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

   int resource;
   RelativeLayout placeView;
   EditText addressText;



   public AddressAdapter(Context _context, int _resource, List<Item> _items) {
       super(_context, _resource, _items);
       resource = _resource;
   }



   private OnClickListener buttonClick = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick (View v) {
       int i = placeView.findViewById(R.id.stub_import).getVisibility();
       visibility(i);
     }
   }


   private void visibility(int i) {
    //

   TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(i) {
       case(View.GONE): 
         addressText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         break;
       case(View.VISIBLE): 
         addressText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         break;
   }



   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     Item item = getItem(position);

     String name = item.getName();
     String address = item.getAddress();

     if (convertView == null) {
       placeView = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
       String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
       vi.inflate(resource, placeView, true);
     } 
     else 
     {
       placeView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
     }

     TextView nameText = (TextView)placeView.findViewById(R.id.placeNamwView);
     Button button = (Button)placeView.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
     addressText = (EditText)placeView.findViewById(R.id.placeAddressText);

     button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);
     nameText.setText(name);
     addressText.setText(address);

     return placeView;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `placeView` data member for every row. Hence, your button click will be changing the `TextView` visibility in the last row processed by `getView()`, not the row containing the button the user clicked on.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists/RateList/) from one of my books showing the use of interactive widgets in a `ListView` (in this case, a `RatingBar`). In my case, I used `getTag()` and `setTag()`. In your case, you could just call `getParent()` on the `Button` to start navigating around to find the right `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the following in the condition

```
 INVISIBLE
```

instead of

```
  GONE
```

try it!